# Unable to ssh to my desktop

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, ssh

I'm trying to ssh from my mac laptop to my linux desktop.

I ran `ifconfig` on my linux desktop (the target machine) and got the ip address listed under eth0 (the machine is connected via wire - not wirelessly) next to "inet addr:"

I used this ip address in a ping command from my mac, which works as expected.

But when I then try to ssh to the machine using the same address I'm unable to reach the machine:

```
$ ssh -A 172.28.11.243
ssh: connect to host 172.28.11.243 port 22: Connection refused
```

i've googled a bit about what to check next but i'm unclear about what to do. Any pointers would be appreciated.

update 1:

```
$service ssh status
ssh stop/waiting
```

Update 2:

```
$ps -eaf | grep sshd
rabdelaz 23832  8389  0 10:53 pts/1    00:00:00 grep sshd
```

Starting Over:

```
$ifconfig                                                             
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 68:05:ca:16:c6:da  
          inet addr:172.28.11.243  Bcast:172.28.11.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:26758 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12721 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:5683822 (5.6 MB)  TX bytes:2044745 (2.0 MB)
          Memory:f71c0000-f71e0000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:22 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:22 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1476 (1.4 KB)  TX bytes:1476 (1.4 KB)

$service ssh status
ssh stop/waiting
$sudo service ssh start
ssh stop/pre-start, process 2961
$service ssh status
ssh stop/waiting
$grep Port /etc/ssh/ssh_config
#   Port 22
```

Output of the logs:

```
$sudo grep -i ssh /var/log/*log
[sudo] password for rabdelaz: 
/var/log/auth.log:Sep  9 11:17:21 bos-lpwy9 sudo: rabdelaz : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/rabdelaz/workspace/configurations ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/ssh-add  /home/rabdelaz/.ssh/deployed/2013-07-29
/var/log/auth.log:Sep  9 11:18:12 bos-lpwy9 sudo: rabdelaz : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/rabdelaz/workspace/configurations ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/ssh-add /home/rabdelaz/.ssh/deployed/2013-07-29
/var/log/auth.log:Sep  9 11:29:41 bos-lpwy9 sudo: rabdelaz : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/rabdelaz/workspace/configurations ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/ssh-add /home/rabdelaz/.ssh/deployed/2013-07-29
/var/log/auth.log:Sep  9 11:30:58 bos-lpwy9 sudo: rabdelaz : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/rabdelaz/workspace/configurations ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/chmod 777 /home/rabdelaz/.ssh/deployed/2013-07-29
/var/log/auth.log:Sep  9 11:52:04 bos-lpwy9 sudo: rabdelaz : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/rabdelaz ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/chmod 777 /home/rabdelaz/.ssh/deployed/2013-07-29
/var/log/auth.log:Sep  9 12:01:42 bos-lpwy9 sudo: rabdelaz : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/rabdelaz ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/ls -lha /home/rabdelaz/.ssh/deployed/2013-07-29
/var/log/auth.log:Sep  9 12:04:18 bos-lpwy9 sudo: rabdelaz : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/rabdelaz ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/chmod 777 /home/rabdelaz/.ssh/internal/2013-07-29
/var/log/auth.log:Sep  9 12:04:21 bos-lpwy9 sudo: rabdelaz : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/rabdelaz ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/chmod 777 /home/rabdelaz/.ssh/external/2013-07-29
/var/log/auth.log:Sep  9 12:04:39 bos-lpwy9 sudo: rabdelaz : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/rabdelaz ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/chmod 777 /home/rabdelaz/.ssh/internal/2013-07-29
/var/log/auth.log:Sep 11 11:54:01 bos-lpwy9 sudo: rabdelaz : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/rabdelaz/workspace ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/sshd
/var/log/auth.log:Sep 11 11:54:12 bos-lpwy9 sudo: rabdelaz : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/rabdelaz/workspace ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/sshd
/var/log/auth.log:Sep 11 11:54:20 bos-lpwy9 sudo: rabdelaz : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/rabdelaz/workspace ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/sshd start
/var/log/auth.log:Sep 11 11:54:54 bos-lpwy9 sudo: rabdelaz : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/rabdelaz/workspace ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service ssh start
/var/log/auth.log:Sep 11 13:36:11 bos-lpwy9 sudo: rabdelaz : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/rabdelaz/workspace/automation ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/apt-get install  libdbi-perl libdate-calc-perl libdbd-mysql-perl libxml-easyobj-perl libdbd-pg-perl libnetaddr-ip-perl libjson-perl libconfig-json-perl libio-pty-perl libnet-ssh-perl libtext-diff-perl libwww-mechanize-perl libtext-csv-perl p4perl libxml-simple-perl liblog-log4perl-perl libyaml-libyaml-perl libdevel-stacktrace-perl libexception-class-perl libdatetime-perl libtest-deep-perl libperl-critic-perl
/var/log/auth.log:Sep 11 14:02:12 bos-lpwy9 sudo: rabdelaz : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/rabdelaz/workspace/automation ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/cpan httpssh
/var/log/auth.log:Sep 12 10:56:31 bos-lpwy9 sudo: rabdelaz : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/rabdelaz/workspace/automation ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service ssh start
/var/log/auth.log:Sep 12 11:13:19 bos-lpwy9 sudo: rabdelaz : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/rabdelaz/workspace/automation ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service ssh start
/var/log/auth.log:Sep 12 11:13:23 bos-lpwy9 sudo: rabdelaz : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/rabdelaz/workspace/automation ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service ssh start
/var/log/auth.log:Sep 12 11:15:46 bos-lpwy9 sudo: rabdelaz : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/rabdelaz/workspace/automation ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service sshd start
/var/log/auth.log:Sep 12 11:26:40 bos-lpwy9 sudo: rabdelaz : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/rabdelaz/workspace/automation ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service ssh start
/var/log/auth.log:Sep 12 11:55:29 bos-lpwy9 sudo: rabdelaz : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/rabdelaz/workspace ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/grep -i ssh /var/log/auth.log /var/log/boot.log /var/log/centrifydc-install.log /var/log/centrify_mapper_error.log /var/log/daemon.log /var/log/dpkg.log /var/log/faillog /var/log/fontconfig.log /var/log/jockey.log /var/log/kern.log /var/log/lastlog /var/log/lpr.log /var/log/mail.log /var/log/pm-powersave.log /var/log/pycentral.log /var/log/syslog /var/log/ufw.log            /var/log/user.log /var/log/Xorg.0.log
/var/log/dpkg.log:2013-09-11 13:36:18 install libnet-ssh-perl <none> 0.09-1
/var/log/dpkg.log:2013-09-11 13:36:18 status half-installed libnet-ssh-perl 0.09-1
/var/log/dpkg.log:2013-09-11 13:36:18 status half-installed libnet-ssh-perl 0.09-1
/var/log/dpkg.log:2013-09-11 13:36:18 status unpacked libnet-ssh-perl 0.09-1
/var/log/dpkg.log:2013-09-11 13:36:18 status unpacked libnet-ssh-perl 0.09-1
/var/log/dpkg.log:2013-09-11 13:36:24 configure libnet-ssh-perl 0.09-1 0.09-1
/var/log/dpkg.log:2013-09-11 13:36:24 status unpacked libnet-ssh-perl 0.09-1
/var/log/dpkg.log:2013-09-11 13:36:24 status half-configured libnet-ssh-perl 0.09-1
/var/log/dpkg.log:2013-09-11 13:36:24 status installed libnet-ssh-perl 0.09-1
```

Comment: make sure that open ssh is installed in your remote machine

Comment: make sure that you arent blocking your connection with iptables or some other firewall. also make sure that you have the program running as DEFCON said and that it is running on 22 not some other port (should be, it's the standard, but it's worth looking up.)

Comment: Is that really your computer's internal IP? It looks like an external one. WHat is the output of `service ssh status` on the linux box?

Comment: Or you can do `ps -eaf|grep sshd` to check if you have a ssh daemon running.

Comment: Do you have more than 1 eth device on the linux box? Have you made any changes to the default routing on either machine? Double check the IP is correct and that SSH is running on the default port. Also check you didn't include an option to use keys with your SSH connections.

Comment: @terdon - posted the output of `service ssh status`. looks like it's not running? @Rik - that grep doesn't return anything but the grep itself.

Comment: Just run `sudo service ssh start` and then try to connect again. Let us know if this does not persist after a reboot.

Comment: i ran sudo `service ssh start`, but was still unable to ssh to the remote machine. I've restarted the machine and the service is once again stopped.

Comment: OK, start over. Please run these commands in order and add their output to your question. `ifconfig`,`service ssh status`,`sudo service ssh start`,`service ssh status`, and then try to connect and give us the output again. If it still does not work, also post the output of `grep Port /etc/ssh/ssh_config`. In all cases, include the exact error (not "did not work") .

Comment: posted the sequence of commands and output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, for some reason your `ssh` service does not want to start. There should be some information in the logs, try

```
sudo grep -i ssh /var/log/*log
```

Then post the output and we an have a look.

I would guess, however, that simply reinstalling your `ssh` server should fix it. If you are OK with losing any changes you have made to your `ssh` configuration, try this:

```
sudo apt-get purge openssh-server ssh
sudo apt-get install openssh-server ssh
sudo service ssh start
```

Then try logging in from your other machine again.

Comment: sweet. I just reinstalled ssh like you suggested and viola! Thanks!

Comment: Really, it gave you a [stringed instrument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viola)? Cool! Sorry, I could't resist when I saw that typo :).

Comment: It could also be a woman named Viola or a viola-flower ;)